# Applescript: how to "tell" an app in the background?

Tags: background, applescript

I'm using Chrome to get the HTML of a webpage which is generated by javascript.  The applescript which does all this needs to run every 2 minutes.  Everything is working perfectly, except that I obviously need Chrome to do this completely in the background.  My script contains the following uses of Chrome (as well as a block to set `theTab`, which doesn't seem to ever cause Chrome to come to the front):

```
set URL of theTab to theURL
set isLoading to (loading of theTab)
execute front window's active tab javascript javascriptLocation
set theSource to execute front window's active tab javascript "document.documentElement.outerHTML"
```

Putting this line:

```
tell application "Finder" to set visible of process "Google Chrome" to false
```

after each of the above lines either produces no hiding at all, or at best Chrome flashes onscreen and then goes away.  I find this very distracting.

Is there any way to have an application run *reliably and permanently* in the backround?  Or, failing this, is there an invisible way to get javascript executed server-side so an applescript can get hold of its generated source?

Chrome 66.0.3359.181 running on Mac OS 10.11.6, Applescript 2.5.

Comment: If all you want is the HTML, why not use CURL to get it? Or write a simple tool of some sort? (Maybe I'm not understanding why you need a full-fledged GUI application to do the work here.)

Comment: Or if you want to run headless JavaScript, try PhantomJS: http://phantomjs.org

Comment: I'm not certain about this since I almost never do anything with the web except use it, but I'm pretty sure I need to get the javascript executed on the server side.  I tried various things (which I can't remember now, this was months ago) to achieve that and found Chrome was the only one that worked.  Is it possible with the tools you mention?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of PhantomJS, I'd never heard of headless mode.  Turns out Chrome can also run headless, in command line mode, and has an option (--dump-dom) that will do exactly what I want.  My code is now much shorter, cleaner, AND I don't have to have Chrome running 24/7 just so I can get my HTML!  Thanks so much :-)

Comment: Excellent! You should answer your own question, and in 48 hours you can accept your answer. This can be useful to others, I think.

Comment: Well, I thought of that, but figured you deserved the credit more than me :-)

Comment: Not at all. I had no idea Chrome itself could run headless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not an answer to the question I posted, but it *is* an answer to the problem I was trying to solve which is why I posted the question.

As stated in my question, I need to get hold of the HTML which some javascript generates on a site (which is not under my control).  I can't do a client-side scrape because of CORS restrictions on the site.  I tried the cross-domain tools listed [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86) and couldn't get them to work.

So I was using Chrome's applescript command, `execute`, to first execute the javascript (to produce the HTML), and then a second time to grab hold of the HTML with `document.documentElement.outerHTML`.  But having Chrome flash onto the screen every 2 minutes throughout the day was doing my head in.

Turns out Chrome can also run in [headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), from the command line, and just happens to have an option to run javascript and return the generated HTML!

So my code got a whole lot simpler and I don't have to have Chrome in my apps list all the time.  Happy coder am I :-)

Here's the one line that gets me the HTML generated on the site I need:

```
set theSource to (do shell script ((quoted form of POSIX path of googlePath) & " --headless --dump-dom " & theURL))
```

Thanks, once again, @matt.  I'd never heard of headless mode and would never have found this without your suggestion of PhantomJS!